# Day.js support for JSON formatted Timespan parsing (e.g. 14.06:10:36)

Tags: typescript, timespan, dayjs

I was using Moment.js until now to parse JSON formatted time spans from a REST API. The time span in the JSON response is formatted in the very common "dd.hh:mm:ss" (e.g. "14.06:10:36" for 14 days, 6 hours, 10 minutes and 36 seconds) format.

Moment.js has an easy way of parsing it, but to my surprise I could not find a way to parse those time span string with day.js. For most purposes day.js is a great replacement for moment.js, which is in maintenance mode now and also has a much larger memory footprint.

Is there anything I missed, or is there a way to parse time span strings with day.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Dayjs durations](https://day.js.org/docs/en/durations/durations#docsNav). You'll probably wanna use regex to parse it first.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import duration from "dayjs/plugin/duration";

dayjs.extend(duration);

const str = "14.06:10:36";

const groups = str.match(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);


const dayjsDuration = dayjs.duration({
  days: parseInt(groups[1]!),
  hours: parseInt(groups[2]!),
  minutes: parseInt(groups[3]!),
  seconds: parseInt(groups[4]!)
})
```

Comment: I tried different things with the duration plugin, but was kind of surprised I could not find a built in option to parse the string. The regex solution might be the best workaround for this.

Comment: They have a great extension system, you can write your own plugin if you really need it.

Comment: I ended up with this "(?:(\d{1,3}).)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})" regex for now, as the days are optional it seems, and depending on the format specifier hours, minutes and seconds can just be one digit. MS Timespan.ToString(...) reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

There is a [duration plugin](https://day.js.org/docs/en/durations/creating). That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I used the duration plugin, but it does not support parsing the duration from a "dd.hh:mm:ss" fomated string.